Integral with two Exponential Distributions
X~exp($\lambda$) and Y~ exp($\mu$) are two independent variables.
I am trying to figure out how to solve for $E[X^{\theta -1} 1_{X<Y}]$.
I believe this could be expressed as:
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{Y}X^{\theta-1}f_{X}(X)f_{Y}(Y) dX dY \\
= \int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{Y}X^{\theta-1}\lambda_{X}e^{-\lambda_{X} X}\lambda_{Y}e^{-\lambda_{Y} Y} dX dY
$$
I think (although I'm not sure) that this could be simplified to:
$$
= \int_{0}^{\infty}\lambda_{X}^{1-\theta}[\Gamma(\theta)-\Gamma(\theta,\lambda_{X}*Y)]\lambda_{Y}e^{-\lambda_{Y} Y} dY
$$
where $\Gamma$ is the gamma function.
I am stuck at this point, could anyone please help. Thank you!

What you compute is $\mathbb{E}(X^\theta 1_{X<Y})$ not the conditional expectation.

Thank you, I’ve edited my question!

The random variable $$Z = X^{\theta-1} \mathbb 1 (X < Y) = \begin{cases} 0, & X \ge Y \\ X^{\theta-1}, & X < Y \end{cases}$$ has expectation
$$\begin{align}
\operatorname{E}[Z] &= \int_{x=0}^\infty \int_{y=0}^\infty x^{\theta - 1} \mathbb 1 (x < y) f_{X,Y}(x,y) \, dy \, dx \\
&= \int_{x=0}^\infty \int_{y=x}^\infty x^{\theta - 1} \lambda e^{-\lambda x} \mu e^{-\mu y} \, dy \, dx \\
&= \int_{x=0}^\infty x^{\theta-1} \lambda e^{-\lambda x} e^{-\mu x} \, dx \\
&= \frac{\Gamma(\theta) \lambda}{(\lambda + \mu)^\theta} \int_{x=0}^\infty \frac{(\lambda + \mu)^\theta x^{\theta-1} e^{-(\lambda+\mu) x}}{\Gamma(\theta)} \, dx \\
&= \frac{\Gamma(\theta) \lambda}{(\lambda + \mu)^\theta}.
\end{align}$$
Note that this variable $Z$ is zero whenever $X \ge Y$, which occurs with probability $$\Pr[X \ge Y] = \frac{\mu}{\lambda + \mu}.$$  It is not equivalent to the conditional expectation $$\operatorname{E}[X^{\theta-1} \mid X < Y] = \frac{\operatorname{E}[Z]}{\Pr[X < Y]} = \frac{\Gamma(\theta)}{(\lambda + \mu)^{\theta-1}}.$$

This is very useful, thank you!
